# What are possible ways to find a startup to join remotely?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-classic, ico

I was wondering which ways there would be to find remote work for an Ethereum or Ethereum Classic based startup. Or some other crypto, who knows.

My goal is to co-found a startup so I can get crypto assets and even fiat money for the compensation of my work.

My skills include many programming languages and business skills. I have a university degree in computer science if that matters.

And the most important thing is that I believe in this crypto stuff.

So, where to find like minded people to join forces with?

Comment: If you are a developer then hanging around in various project Gitter chats or such is a good place to start.  Also contributing to open source projects is an efficient way to demostrate that you really have technical skills.